# How can I get the filesystem path for a JTree root node?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I noticed in the following code

```
DefaultTreeModel treemodel = new DefaultTreeModel();
TreeNode root = treeModel.getRoot();
```

The problems is that `root` value is "root" not the path to the file on the file system.

What I would expect is something like "C:\" or "D:\" depending on the tree.

Any one run into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is not exactly what are you asking, but here is an tutorial/example of how to implement a file tree.

http://www.chka.de/swing/tree/FileTreeModel.html

Comment: For comparison, another `FileTreeModel` is cited [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).